# Update records with random number

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a 200k rows mysql table, and a column with empty value, and i like to populate this column with random numbers from 1 to 10,000.

I don't know if its possible to have a query something like this:

```
UPDATE 'videos'
SET 'views' = rand(1,10000)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`RAND()` produces random float values from 0 to 1. Could you try this?

```
Update videos set views = CAST(RAND() * 10000 AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. It can generate a random number between 1 to 10000.

```
UPDATE videos
SET views = FLOOR(rand() * 10000) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```sql
UPDATE videos SET views = FLOOR(1 + rand() * 10000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

updating Table records with random phone numbers

```
DECLARE @OrderDetailID INT
DECLARE @Phone VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
            OrderDetailID
    FROM    dbo.OrderDetailTBL

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @OrderDetailID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
    --Do something with Id here
        SET @Phone = '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CONVERT(NUMERIC(3, 0), RAND()
            * 899)) + ') ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CONVERT(NUMERIC(3, 0), RAND()
            * 899)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CONVERT(NUMERIC(4, 0), RAND()
            * 8999))


        UPDATE  dbo.OrderDetailTBL
        SET     ShippingPhone = @Phone
        WHERE   OrderDetailID = @OrderDetailID
        FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @OrderDetailID
    END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to update one column with **random number between some range and having -Ve type** too, then you can use the below code :

```
UPDATE DataBase.TableName
SET Column = ((4 * RAND()) - (4 * RAND()))
WHERE IndexColumn > 0; -- here I have taken range between 4 to -4
```